# unable find Provisioning Profiles in xcode due space

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I want Build, it shows me below error:

> security: unable to open "/Users/antonio/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/.mobileprovision" for reading: No such file or directory

When cding into this directory using terminal, it show me this error:

```
$ cd /Users/antonio/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
-bash: cd: /Users/antonio/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning: No such file or directory
```

But it is available when I going to this directory using Finder.

I think due it have space in the name, it can't open,is there any way I change name of `Provisioning Profiles`?

Answer (score 1):

```
cd "/Users/antonio/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles"
```

or

```
cd /Users/antonio/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
```

more on this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/398400/how-do-i-navigate-to-folders-with-spaces-in-their-names-i-get-no-such-file-or

Comment: it not help, cause xcode not detect it, how i can solve it in xcode?